# Улучшение перевода на странице синонимов метки

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, синонимы-меток

На [странице](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2B%2B/synonyms) синонимов метки [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), которая на текущий момент выглядит так:

> [image: скриншот страницы]

наблюдаются следующие проблемы:

1. Вместо фразы `Синонимы метки для c++` должно быть `Синонимы для метки c++` (или вовсе убрать `для`);
2. Вместо фразы `Следующие метки будут присвоены` должно быть `Следующим меткам будет присвоена метка`;
3. Пропущен перевод для `and` между метками;
4. Вместо `Предложить синоним метки` должны быть `Предложить синоним для метки` (или оставить как есть, но надо согласовать с п.1).

Возможно, указанные проблемы актуальны и для других меток.

---

[Tx:4211](http://d56081e8585158c2c92ac96c296ab42a)

> The following tags will be remapped to $tagLink$
>   Следующие метки будут присвоены

Comment: Указанные проблемы актуальны для любой метки.

Comment: This is an invalid translation, only used here. It can be [fixed on Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40266100?q=Tag%20synonyms%20for%20%24tagLink%24)

Comment: @m0sa we usually mark invalid or missing translations as [tag:bug]s. It's what they are to users.

Comment: oic, was to quick there, google translate sucks... the issue is with the `and` between the tags

Comment: @m0sa yep. I've just tried to find single untranslated "and" in the Transifex, but it doesn't seem to be there.

Comment: @m0sa by the way, all cases where a translation string is missing from Transifex are marked with [tag:нет-в-transifex]. Feel free to ask for translation or clarificaton.

Comment: oh, this is gonna be fun, [another one of those](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/720194283303800833) inbound

Comment: @NickVolynkin strings are [on transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/91216591?q=%24tag0%24)

Comment: @m0sa oh, thanks )

Comment: @m0sa, would like to see ending of `default` one)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Следующие метки будут присвоены

Суть в том, что если добавить к вопросу метку [cpp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpp), она будет автоматически заменена на [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Поэтому предлгаю такой вариант:

> Следующие метки заменяются на [c++](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)

---

Кстати, в русском языке "байк" - это мотоцикл. Предлагаю заменить на "велик".

---

> Синонимы метки для c++

убрал "для".

Comment: Добавил «велик». Будем ждать пересборок.